# Problem with displayed coordinates in LogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting

I have a very weird problem that I don't usually get. I try to plot a set of equations using `LogLinearPlot` and the **Get coordinates** right-click menuitem is working just fine. However, when I change the parameter, I right click in the image to get the coordinate, however displayed coordinate value is inconsistent with the axis. I point at around 100 to 1000 but it gives me -0.02631. This problem does not always appear and it depends on the parameters I use (`ash`, `csh`, etc.). [image]

Can anyone please help me what might cause this issue? I never had this problem before. I am using *Mathematica* v8.

I'm sorry for dumping my code. It is given because I don't know how to make it simpler.

```
<< "PlotLegends`"

bsh[ash_, Gs_, s0_] := ash/Gs*s0/100;
w[af_, nf_, mf_, ws_, \[Psi]_] := ws/(
     (Log[Exp[1] + (\[Psi]/af)^nf])^mf);
e[ash_, csh_, w_, Gs_, s0_] := ash*(
     ((((w/100)^csh)/(bsh[ash, Gs, s0]^csh)) + 1)^(1/csh));
s[af_, nf_, mf_, ws_, \[Psi]_, ash_, csh_, Gs_, s0_] := (
     w[af, nf, mf, ws, \[Psi]]*
     Gs/e[ash, csh, w[af, nf, mf, ws, \[Psi]], Gs, s0]);

Gs = 2.61; ws = 44.664; ll = 64; s0 = 98.373;
af = 1049; nf = 3.83; mf = 1.6; ash = 0.878; csh = 36.52;

LogLinearPlot[{
  s[af, nf, mf, ws, \[Psi], 0.9, csh, Gs, s0], 
  s[af, nf, mf, ws, \[Psi], 2*ash, csh, Gs, s0], 
  s[af, nf, mf, ws, \[Psi], ash, csh, Gs, s0], 
  s[af, nf, mf, ws, \[Psi], 0.5*ash, csh, Gs, s0], 
  s[af, nf, mf, ws, \[Psi], 0.25, csh, Gs, s0]}, 
{\[Psi], 0.01, 1000000},
 ImageSize ->400, AxesStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> {0, 100}, 
 LabelStyle -> {Bold, 14}, AxesLabel -> {"\[Psi]", "S"}, 
 PlotLegend -> {"4ash", "2ash", "ash", "0.5ash", "0.25ash"},
 LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.4}, LegendTextSpace -> 1,
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick, Dashed, Dotted, DotDashed}]
```

Comment: Could you add how you made the plot ?

Comment: Ok. I just add it. \[psi] is a esc y esc symbol. I dont know why it change into \[psi]

Comment: My idea is that the `PlotLegends` package messes up the coordinates. Removing the legend-related options fixes it. Can you use the version 9 built in `PlotLegends` option instead of the (now obsolete) package?

Comment: Ahh, I see, you are on v8. Then I guess you have to construct your own legend from scratch.

Comment: Ah I see....glad to know what is the cause. Thx

Answer (score 2):

In version 9 one can use the builtin `PlotLegends` option, but pre-9 it seems like the `` "PlotLegends`" `` package messes up coordinate display. In this case, fall back to create your own legend. For that, define styles and labels outside of the plot so that your legend can use them too.

```
styles = {Red, Thick, Dashed, Dotted, DotDashed};
labels = {"4ash", "2ash", "ash", "0.5ash", "0.25ash"};
legend = Panel@Grid@MapThread[{Graphics[{#1, Line@{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}}, ImageSize -> 30, 
        AspectRatio -> .3], #2} &, {styles, labels}];
Row@{
  LogLinearPlot[Evaluate[{
      s[af, nf, mf, ws, \[Psi], 0.9, csh, Gs, s0],
      s[af, nf, mf, ws, \[Psi], 2*ash, csh, Gs, s0],
      s[af, nf, mf, ws, \[Psi], ash, csh, Gs, s0],
      s[af, nf, mf, ws, \[Psi], 0.5*ash, csh, Gs, s0],
      s[af, nf, mf, ws, \[Psi], 0.25, csh, Gs, s0]} /. par],
    {\[Psi], 0.01, 1000000},
     ImageSize -> 400, AxesStyle -> Thick, LabelStyle -> {Bold, 14},
     AxesLabel -> {"\[Psi]", "S"}, PlotRange -> {0, 100}, PlotStyle -> styles],
  legend
  }
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]